# SQLite database not open

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt-creator

i have this problem when i check  for the database it's opened in  this line it gives true

```
    bool opened = PatternLibrary.open();
    if(opened){
```

But when i try to execute the query of table creation it fails giving this output

```
    QSqlQuery::prepare: database not open
```

This is my Code

```
    PatternLibrary = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase( "QSQLITE" );
    PatternLibrary.setDatabaseName( "./Library.db" );
    bool opened = PatternLibrary.open();
    if(opened)
    {
       qDebug( "Connected!");
       query.prepare( "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Pattern (patternName VARCHAR(30),RectangleID   INTEGER ,minWidth INTEGER, minHeight INTEGER, maxWidth INTEGER, maxHeight INTEGER, X Integer, Y INTEGER)" );
       bool create = query.exec();
       if(!create)
       {
           qDebug() <<PatternLibrary.lastError().text();
       }

    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << PatternLibrary.lastError().text();
        qFatal( "Failed to connect." );
    }
```

Comment: Please show how you initialize `query`.

Comment: I found the solution I  had to create  QSqlQuery query after opening the database 
now it's working just fine

Comment: @CL. i am using a class where i have 2 members
QSqlDatabase PatternLibrary;
QSqlQuery query;
this piece of code i've posted is from my construcor

is there anyway to set my query with this database and keep my code as it is ?

Comment: QSqlConnection is reference counted object, so when you initilize your query, you pass unopened copy. When you open database, the first connection cannot known about it